# Opening tsv format Eurostat data

Tags: file-io, csv

I've been trying to open this data: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/estat-navtree-portlet-prod/BulkDownloadListing?sort=1&file=data%2Fdemo_gind.tsv.gz. I've already unzipped it and get the tsv file, but when I opened it in gedit, it looks like a binary file. Could anybody help me to open this file?

Comment: .gz stands for gzip, which is pretty much like zip, rar, 7z and so on. You will need some software to unzip (decompress) the file, like for example 7zip: http://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 3):

The file is correctly formatted even if not so readable for human beings.

> TSV is a file extension for a tab-delimited file used with spreadsheet
>   software. TSV stands for Tab Separated Values. TSV files are used for
>   raw data and can be imported into and exported from spreadsheet
>   software. TSV files are essentially text files, and the raw data can
>   be viewed by text editors, though they are often used when moving raw
>   data between spreadsheets.

You can import it inside Excel or Open Office. Otherwise you may convert it by using online service (example google sheets).

Comment: It turns out that tsv file inside gz is an archive. I need to decompress the tsv once again. Thanks.

Comment: How did you decompress?

Comment: Fast and easy using the tool Ark.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've unarchived the original .gz file there are two more steps required to view the data, as noted on [Eurostat's website](http://www.eui.eu/Research/Library/ResearchGuides/Economics/Statistics/DataPortal/EDD.aspx).

> TSV files may be imported into Excel by (1) Saving on hard disk with
>   the suffix .tsv and (2) unzipping and (3) saving the table(s) as Text
>   (*.txt).

1. As per user74158's comment, decompress/unzip the tsv file. This can
   likely be done with many different programs, I used 7zip and it
   worked for me. On windows 7 I did this by right clicking, hovering
   over 7zip, selecting extract files, tell 7zip where you'd like to
   extract the files too and press OK.
2. Next go to the file, and change the .tsv file extension to .txt. Answer yes, you're sure you want to change the file extension and then you should be able to read the data.